# Unwanted delay caused by interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, intervals

Working on character animation for a super simple jQuery game.

My problem is that there is about a half second delay if you switch between the movement keys quickly. For example, if you are holding down W then press D very quickly there is an unwanted delay. I want it to be instant. Is there any way to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var character = $('#character');
    var movement;
    var move_keys = {
        87: {top: "-=1"}, // up
        83: {top: "+=1"}, // down
        65: {left: "-=1"}, // left
        68: {left: "+=1"} // right
    };
    var moving = false;
    var move_timer;

    $(this).keydown(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!moving) {
            moving = true;
            movement = move_keys[e.keyCode];
            move_timer = setInterval(startMoving, 1);
        }
    });

    $(this).keyup(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        moving = false;
        clearInterval(move_timer);
    });

    function startMoving() {
        if (movement !== undefined) {
            character.css(movement);
        }
    }
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4rycer59/1/

Comment: Approximately how long is the delay?

Comment: Check the jsfiddle, it is approx. half a second and doesn't happen 100% of the time.

Comment: Your issue happens when you press the new key before releasing the old.  The delay is waiting for your Operating System key-repeat functionality to trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When keys are pressed simultaneously, you will receive keyboard events in a different order.

I made the following changes:

```
var moving; // no longer boolean
var move_timer;

$(this).keydown(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (moving !== e.keyCode) {
        moving = e.keyCode; // which key is moving?
        movement = move_keys[e.keyCode];
        clearInterval(move_timer); // just in case keyup is late
        move_timer = setInterval(startMoving, 1);
    }
});

$(this).keyup(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(moving === e.keyCode) { // only cancel if not 'late'
        moving = false;
        clearInterval(move_timer);
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lc8hcnnw/7/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest separating the key press logic from the movement logic. It makes things easier to reason about and will allow for movement in multiple directions. You can also improve the game loop by using `setTimeout` rather than `setInterval` so that you run the game logic as often as possible. Then if you account for the delta time (the time since the last game loop) you can smooth the movement further since `setInterval` and `setTimeout` do not always delay for the exact same amount of time.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var character = $('#character');

    var position = character.position();

    var keysPressed = {};

    $(this).keydown(function (e) {
        keysPressed[e.keyCode] = true;
    });

    $(this).keyup(function (e) {
        delete keysPressed[e.keyCode];
    });

    function loop(callback, lastTime) {
        var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        callback(currentTime - lastTime);
        setTimeout(function () {
            loop(callback, currentTime);
        });
    }

    loop(function(deltaTime) {

        // Use delta from last frame to "smooth" movement
        var steps =  deltaTime / 10;

        if (keysPressed[87]) { // UP
            position.top -= steps;
        }
        if (keysPressed[83]) { // DOWN
            position.top += steps;
        }

        if (keysPressed[65]) { // LEFT
            position.left -= steps;
        }
        if (keysPressed[68]) { // RIGHT
            position.left += steps;
        }

        character.css(position);
    });
});
```